# PHP Using MD5 to secure a $_GET function

Tags: php, security, hash, get

I'm using a $_GET function in php to perform functions for my Java server.

The website is similar to this: http://api.somewebsite.com/perform/function.php?authkey1=randomMD5&authkey2=randomMD5&parameters=something

Where the variables *authkey1* and *authkey2* represent a randomly generated MD5. The PHP script does connect to MySQL, and I've already prevented injection. However, before anything else gets parsed by the code, the URL has to include those 2 authkeys or else they get a message saying, "Improper authentication".

Here's an example of what my code does:

```
// Security key check
$key1 = "skghlskfhgj42u6928749856478937683471095sndgfnsvnrandom";
$key2 = "dbnksgh794ytowhjklgn934ngmsnnmlrj9096345u075u80375ngsr";

$g_key1 = $_GET['authkey1'];
$g_key2 = $_GET['authkey2'];

if (empty($g_key1) || empty($g_key2)) {
die("Improper authorization");
}

if ($g_key1 != $key1 || $g_key2 != $key2) {
die("Improper authorization");
}

// If authentication passes, move on to other functions
```

Is this method secure or not? Thanks!

Comment: I know those aren't MD5's in $key1 and $key2. It's just an example.

Comment: nope it can be cached.

Comment: Using MD5-hashed strings doesn't really make a difference here, does it? You could just use any old random string. That said, this is somewhat secure - except that the URL may get logged along the way, in proxies, and in your own server's access log. I wouldn't use it to secure a bank transaction, but for many other less sensitive uses it's fine.

Comment: It's exposed to the "man in the middle" attack.

Comment: You may be vulnerable to a replay attack. Are you marking your keys used?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track by having two secret keys, but the people in the comments above are all correct.  This is not particularly secure.  What would I do? I would make one shared key that your two servers know about.  A key like

```
$key1 = "skghlskfhgj42u6928749856478937683471095sndgfnsvnrandom";
```

This key become the salt to some sort of operation you perform on all the parameters. Both servers use the salt to build a hash which is passed on the request. The receiving end of the script will check to make sure the passed hash is the same that it would build from the request.

```
$passed_hash = $_GET['hash'];

$params = $_GET;
unset($params['hash']);
ksort($params);
$str = '';
foreach($params as $k => $v){
  $str .= $v;
}

// the key is the salt
$str .= $key1;

$calculated_hash = md5($str);

if($passed_hash == $calculated_hash){
  // you know everything is good
}
```

Make sure to include timestamp in the request so no two requests are the same.

Comment: Would it be possible to just check the IP of the person requesting visiting the PHP page? There would only be 1 or 2 different IPs that would need to access that function.

Comment: Yes.  That should be in the $_SERVER superglobal.  See this search (or a quick google search on spoofing IPs) to understand the security risks your run there http://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed. I offered a secure solution that would be easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

No, that method is not secure, but rather "security by obscurity".

First and most important, use [TLS/SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  Second, find a 3rd party library to handle request authentication for you.  I couldn't find one that did what I needed, so I put one together myself.

The library is called [Query Auth](https://github.com/jeremykendall/query-auth) and I wrote it to handle this exact use case.  It's a generic implementation of the [Signature Version 2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Signature/SignatureV2.php) implementation from the [AWS SDK for PHP 2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Signature/SignatureV2.php).  It handles API key and API secret generation, signature creation and validation, and can optionally protect against replay attacks.  Documentation and an [example implementation](https://github.com/jeremykendall/query-auth-impl) are available.